# instead of starting, it is saying "there is a file with the same name in this location" when i put The pk3 over GZdoom (Myhouse.wad)

Tags: doom-2

it wont start instead saying "there is  a file with the same name in this location"
i have tried putting the PK3 on GZdoom but it wont work

Comment: Post a screenshot of file explorer of where gzdoom.exe is

Comment: Is the pk3 in the same directory as the GZDoom executable? Have you tried running GZDoom in Administrator mode?